# ios resize scrollview by containerview with tavleview inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, size, uicontainerview

I have next structure of views:

```
vc
-view
--safe area
--scrollview
---view
----containerview1
----containerview2
----containerview3
-----tableviewcontroller(in containervew3)
```

Tableviewcontroller has buttons which add or remove rows, I want to resize scroll view that it shows full tableview content(without scrolling in tableview). I tried to solution like: from [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11222) or [Sizing a Container View with a controller of dynamic size inside a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014362/sizing-a-container-view-with-a-controller-of-dynamic-size-inside-a-scrollview)  but without success. I use iOS 10.0&swift

Answer (score 0):

First thing is constraints. You must have proper constraints with `UIScrollView` and container's view

Next thing you need is height constraints of `tableviewController` (you can give height to 0 with relation greater than equal with 750 priority so constrains would never break if something wrong happened)

Take IBOutlet of that height constraint when your data insert / delete happen your content size will change and apply that contentsize height to constant of IBOutlet constraint and don't forgot to layoutIfNeeded.

Make your tableview scrolling bounce to false

create `protocol` to notify container view about height change

```
protocol ContainerTableDelegate {
      func dataChanged(height: CGFloat)
 }
```

and when height change notify parent view controller

```
    delegate?.dataChanged(self.heightConstraint.constant)
```

Now in the main viewcontroller where you have all containers

implement

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

identify ViewController set delegate to `self` implement delegate and change height of container view 3 constant (You also need this)

Hope it will help to solve your issue

Comment: Thank for response Prashant Tukadiya, but unfortunately, container view does not change its size, I tried also make it bigger than needed by multiply , delegate works, constraint sets, layoutIfNeeded also calls(I checked it by manually making scrollview content size bigger in function which applies new height) also I tried to add tableviewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false but without success

Comment: @AntonLisitsyn I have created UIView and give height constraint to it. in that view i have added container view. on some button even I am changing height constraints's   constant value and accordingly container view also changes.  So It should work