# Containerview inside scrollview not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout, xcode-storyboard

The stack of my views is this:

```
superView
-scrollview = CONSTRAINTS(leading: superView, trailing: superView, top: superView, bottom: superView)
--view = CONSTRAINTS(leading: superView, trailing: superView, top: superView, bottom: superView, equalWidth: scrollView, equalHeight[priority: 250]: scrollView)
---collectionView = CONSTRAINTS(leading: view, trailing: view, top: view, height: 50)
---containerView = CONSTRAINTS(leading: view, trailing: view, top: collectionView, bottom: view)
```

I've search all the questions that about containerView inside scrollview but none of it solve my problem.

Comment: have you give fixed height to collectionview?

Comment: yep collectionview has a fixed height of 50

Comment: How does it work using equalHeight[priority: 250]: scrollView. Height of view must be higher than scrollview.

Comment: These constraints don't imply scrolling. The `view` height is equal to the `scrollview` height. `collectionview` has 50 height and `containerview` takes the rest of the space. To make it scrollable the height of the `view` should be bigger than the height of the `scrollview`

Comment: @AlexanderGaidukov yes I realized that if I set constraint height for containerView it will now scroll, but the problem is that the containerView height should not be fixed because containerView height will depend on the embedded view

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve this by setting the embedded view to `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` put it in prepareForSegue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 segue.destination.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

my reference: [Sizing a Container View with a controller of dynamic size inside a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014362/sizing-a-container-view-with-a-controller-of-dynamic-size-inside-a-scrollview/35431534)